# Which method do you recommend just to pass the headache of XtraReport.CreateDocument?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, devexpress, xtrareport

I have been using DevExpress for a long time and I like the control very much. The only problem I have is the headache that comes with XtraReport.CreateDocument method. Don't get me wrong the report control is state of the art I love it all the way. The only problem I have is with the slow method XtraReport.CreateDocument() or XtraReport.CreateDocument(true).

Can you please recommend me if I have to use the XtraReport control using Dataset or POCO? So that XtraReport.CreateDocument method won't suffer much and cause slowness on the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CreateDocument method is nether slow nor fast - everything depends on the size of your document and the time it takes to fetch the data. I'd recommend asking DevExpress-specific questions on their forum at devexpress.com/ask.